# Conda: how to use system java instead of double installing it?

Tags: java, ubuntu, conda

I'm trying to install `tabula-py` using Conda. It is a wrap over a java library, so it depends on the java runtime. I'm using the Ubuntu from Windows Subsystem for Linux.

When I type `conda install tabula-py -c conda-forge` it tells me that openjdk will be installed. But I'd like to use the system java that I installed using `apt install default-jre`. Is it possible?

I have a small ssd and don't want to waste space with 2 java versions.

Comment: Does it need the JDK or a JRE?

Comment: Good question. I installed it with pip and used the system jre, but the dependency in conda is openjdk. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Well, `openjdk-jre` is a package as well. More specifically, it would need the JDK if it needed to compile any code